# Print 0001 to 1000 in Kotlin. How to add padding to numbers?

Tags: kotlin

I want to print 0001 (note the 3 preceding 0s), and incremental 1 at a time, and reach 1000 to stop. How could I do that in Kotlin without complex appending the 0s myself?

The below is not helping as it will not have preceding 0s.

```
for (i in 1..1000) print(i)
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can use [`padStart`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html):

```
(0..1000)
    .map { it.toString().padStart(4, '0') }
    .forEach(::println)
```

It’s part of the Kotlin Standard Library and available for all platforms.

Comment: Just a small heads up, padStart is to add the preceding 0s using CharSequence Extension function(https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/pad-start.html) And ::println is a reflection. More information: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik well, it is a function reference, but it is stated under the Reflection page in the documentation.

Comment: @GeertBerkers Yeah... deleted the comment. It does sound misleading, but I guess Kotlin uses the term "reflection" differently. In any case, there's no runtime penalty involved with function references.

Answer (score 36):

If you are satisfied with a JVM-specific approach, you can do what you'd to in Java:

```
(1..1000).forEach { println("%04d".format(it)) }
```

`String.format` is an extension function defined in `StringsJVM` and it delegates straight to the underlying `String.format`, so it's not in the universal standard library.

Answer (score 18):

In Kotlin you can use `String.format()` (the same as in Java):

```
"%04d".format(i)
```

In your case, you can write down it in the following way:

```
(1..1000).forEach { println("%04d".format(it)) }
```

Answer (score 11):

Just to be clear, `for`-loops are fine too:

```
for(i in 1..1000)
    println("%04d".format(i))
```

Answer (score 11):

With PadStart and without any map or multiple loops,

```
(0..1000).forEach { println(it.toString().padStart(4, '0')) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a string template will call `toString()` under the hood and make the call even shorter:

```
(0..1000).forEach { println("$it".padStart(4, '0')) }
```

Mapping it first, is unecessary effort.